# Multiple msvcr100.dll versions - where are the differences?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll

When deploying my app, the 2010 redistributable package x86 is needed. Having customers install it by themselves online is cumbersome. I would like to deploy msvcr100.dll and msvcp100.dll myself, which would work fine... However, on my system I can find multiple of these dlls. There is a `redist` folder in the Visual Studio 2010 directory and I used dlls from there, but they do not seem to work globally, either.

I know most of the threads, questions and articles to visual studio deployment on Stackoverflow and findable via Google. None gives a satisfying answer.

But my question here is: Are there multiple versions of msvcr100.dll globally available? If yes, why and how do they differ?

Comment: 8 years gets to be a bit too long to remember accurate.  But yes, there were two service packs and I know for a fact that SP1 had an update for these DLLs.  IIRC there was also a security update affecting MFC.  VS2010 was also the first version that no longer required deployment of the DLLs into the side-by-side cache, so providing a program with its own private copy of them was possible again.  Yay.  Which is the wise choice, over the risk of a wonky installer overwriting them with old versions, just copy the DLLs that you tested with in the same folder as the EXE.

Comment: @HansPassant that’s the thing. I tested it with the dlls and it worked fine for several years. Now, since Win10, maybe earlier, people keep getting problems (0x00000fb) errors or something. The redis 2010 that I can download does the trick, though. Will it work for anyone to use those dlls, though?

Comment: Not sure what you expect me to do with an "or something" error description.  These DLLs have a fairly nasty DLL Hell problem when deployed into c:\windows, I explained why local deployment is the wise choice to avoid somebody's borken installer.  Like it putting the 32-bit flavor into c:\windows\system32, bombs with 0xC000007B.  In turn breaking another program with the redist installer is not a wise choice either, but a way to pass the problem to somebody else.  The end-user is always the hapless victim, he can only get one of them repaired.

Comment: @HansPassant I am just talking about using the DLLs from an installer that works for me into my application folder, I.e. I want to put the dlls locally, but the question is whether the ones that work for me work for anyone? Hard to say